# Assign category based on magnitude of value

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data.table like this

```
dt1=data.table(id=c(001,001,002,002,003,003),
              score=c(4,6,3,7,2,8))
```

where each individual has 2 scores on the variable "score". 
I would like to assign each individual to a category in the variable outcome based on their score.

For their lower score, they get an "A", for their higher, they get a "B". So the final table looks like this

```
dt2=data.table(id=c(001,001,002,002,003,003),
                score=c(4,6,3,7,2,8),
                category=c('A','B', 'A','B', 'A','B'))
```

Since the values in column "score" are random, the category should be assigned based on the magnitude of the numbers assigned to each person. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `ifelse`:

```
library(data.table)
dt1[, category := ifelse(score == min(score), 'A', 'B'), by = id]
```

**Result:**

```
   id score category
1:  1     4        A
2:  1     6        B
3:  2     3        A
4:  2     7        B
5:  3     2        A
6:  3     8        B
```

Answer (score 2):

We can `order` the 'score' in `i`, grouped by 'id' and assign the 'category' as 'A', 'B'

```
library(data.table)
dt1[order(score), category := c('A', 'B') , by = id]
dt1
#    id score category
#1: 001     4        A
#2: 001     6        B
#3: 002     3        A
#4: 002     7        B
#5: 003     2        A
#6: 003     8        B
```

---

Or another option is to convert a logical vector to a numeric index and replace the values based on that

```
dt1[, category := c('A', 'B')[(score != min(score)) + 1] ,by = id]
```

#### data

```
dt1 <- data.table(id=c('001','001','002','002','003','003'), 
                   score=c(4,6,3,7,2,8))
```